# What is a simple way to add and subtract a method to a button, based on a boolean var?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a simple game to help learn javascript. What I want to happen is if game.playerTurn is true, then this extra method is added to my buttons. Conversely, if game.PlayerTurn is false, I don't want this method to execute.

.bind seems to add the method forever (so if statements don't really work). and binding and unbinding seems a bit heavy handed as something to do each round (there are 12 buttons). Can an expert out there point me in the right direction? What would be the normal way to do this?

Further info: when it is the computer's turn, I am using a .trigger function to push the buttons and store their values in an array called game.computer. That all works.

```
if(game.playerTurn){  
    $( "#one" ).bind( "click", function() {
        game.player.push(1);
    });

    $( "#two" ).bind( "click", function() {
        game.player.push(2);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using bind, but [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Also, you can move the `boolean` check inside the function callback instead. This would be a good opportunity to use *named functions* instead of multiple anonymous ones to save some lines of code:

```
$("#one").on("click", doClick(1));
$("#two").on("click", doClick(2));

function doClick(i) {
    return function() {
        if(game.playerTurn) game.player.push(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful! This will trim down my code significantly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong way round:

```
$( "#one" ).bind( "click", function() {
    if(game.playerTurn){
         game.player.push(1);
    }
});
```

As a little aside, you don't need a handler per button, if all your buttons can be identified together, and use a `data-value` attribute you can just have 1 handler:

```
 <button class="numeric" data-value="1">One</button>
 <button class="numeric" data-value="2">Two</button>

$( ".numeric" ).bind( "click", function() {
    if(game.playerTurn){
         game.player.push($(this).data('value'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Just so I am clear:  $(this) would refer to the button clicked and ('value') would refer to the data-value?

Comment: @interestinall pretty much, yes

Comment: @interestinall as the other answer pointed out `bind` is an old way of binding an event handler. Use `on`